# Stack implementation array index out of bound error

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have created a stack .

```
public class STK {
    static int capacity = 0; 

    STK(int size) {
        capacity = size;
    }

    int stackk[] = new int[capacity];
    int top = 0;

    public void push(int d) {
        if(top < capacity) {
            stackk[top] = d;
            top++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Overflow");
        }
    } 
}
```

its implementation

```
public class BasicStackImplementation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        STK mystack = new STK(5);

        mystack.push(51);
        mystack.push(23);
    }
}
```

when i try to run this code it gives an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at STK.push(STK.java:21)
    at BasicStackImplementation.main(BasicStackImplementation.java:6)
```

Comment: You made the array size 0 so you cannot put anything into it. `int stackk[] = new int[capacity];` gets executed before you run your constructor method and at that time `capacity` is 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[JAVA\]Array java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244469/javaarray-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0-error)

Answer (score 1):

Field initializers run before the constructor. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
static int capacity = 0;
int stackk[]=new int[capacity];
STK(int size)
{
    capacity=size;
}
```

So you're initializing an empty array. To fix it, just initialize `stackk` inside the constructor:

```
int[] stackk;
STK(int size)
{
    capacity = size;
    stackk = new int[capacity];
}
```

Also, `capacity` varies by instance and shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: Or just don't have the `capacity` field at all, use `stackk.length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you made your class, you initialized your array property in your class to equal capacity which is 0. So your array is initialized with 0 elements.

When you call your constructor and set the capacity value, you need to re-initialize your class array equal to new int[value]